# Trying to convert a dplyr filter + group_by + summarise into a function using tidyeval

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to create a function which does a group_by and a summarise and filters for each value of a character variable (I've tried before with a factor but asked me for a character).

I know I can resolve this with a filter + group_by + summarise in dplyr, and I've actually done it, this is my original dplyr:

```
index_basic2_migpunts %>% 
  filter(Tramspoblacio == "10000 - 19999") %>% 
  group_by(ccaa) %>% 
  summarise(index_basic_estatal = mean(index_basic_estatal)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(index_basic_estatal))
```

But I want to convert it to a function using tidy eval and dplyr...

This is the function I have written, where data is the dataset, grup_poblacional is the variable that I'm filtering (right now, it is a character variable with different entries such as "10000 - 19999", "20000 - 29999", etc), grup_territorial which is being grouped by. Index_sumarise is the variable that I'm sumarising and afterwards arranging in descending order.

```
mitjana_index3 <- function(data, grup_poblacional, grup_territorial, index_sumarise, filtre){
  
  grup_poblacional <- enquo(grup_poblacional)
  grup_territorial <- enquo(grup_territorial)
  
  data2 <- data %>%
    filter(!!grup_poblacional, filtre) %>%
    group_by(!!grup_territorial) %>%
    summarize(index_sumarise = mean(index_sumarise)) %>% 
    arrange(desc(index_sumarise))
  return(data2)
}
```

and this is how I apply it

`mitjana_index3(index_basic2_migpunts, Tramspoblacio_no_factor, ccaa, index_basic_estatal, "10000 - 19999")`

I get this result:

```
Error in `filter()`:
i In argument: `Tramspoblacio_no_factor`.
Caused by error:
! `..1` must be a logical vector, not a character vector.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
>
```

Thank you really much!

Comment: Can you share some data (either real or using one of the built in data sets) using `dput()` so that we can run your example? Generally, you probably want to look at using `{{ argument }}` instead of `!!` - see https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/06/rlang-0-4-0/#a-simpler-interpolation-pattern-with-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is one way to do it tested on the iris data set.

```r
library(dplyr)

mitjana_index3 <- function(data, grup_poblacional, grup_territorial, index_sumarise, filtre){
  
  data2 <- data %>%
    filter({{ grup_poblacional }} == filtre) %>%
    group_by({{ grup_territorial }}) %>%
    summarize(index_sumarise = mean({{ index_sumarise }})) %>% 
    arrange(desc(index_sumarise))
  
  return(data2)
}


mitjana_index3(iris, Species, Species, Sepal.Length, "virginica")
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   Species   index_sumarise
#>   <fct>              <dbl>
#> 1 virginica           6.59
```

To account for more filter options, I would use the `...` argument and let the user splice in any kind of filter statments.

```r
library(dplyr)

mitjana_index3 <- function(data, grup_territorial, index_sumarise, ...){
    
    filter_expr <- eval(substitute(alist(...)))
    
    data2 <- data %>%
        filter(!!! filter_expr) %>%
        group_by({{ grup_territorial }}) %>%
        summarize(index_sumarise = mean({{ index_sumarise }})) %>% 
        arrange(desc(index_sumarise))
    
    return(data2)
}


mitjana_index3(iris, Species, Sepal.Length, Species != "virginica", Sepal.Length > 5)

#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   Species    index_sumarise
#>   <fct>               <dbl>
#> 1 versicolor           6.00
#> 2 setosa               5.31
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Suggestion - if you want your output to retain `Sepal.Length` for example as the column name instead of `index_sumarise` use `summarize({{index_sumarise}} := mean({{ index_sumarise }}))` - wrapping function argument in `{{}}` here also and using `:=` to assign. Use curlies in `arrange(desc({{index_sumarise}}))` also.

Comment: Is there a way to loop over each filter category ("filtre" in the function) using the function? Thank you!

Comment: @FrancoBattiato: see my updated answer, how my approach would look like. It is open to all kind of filter statements.